# forwarding after authorization NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

There is such a router on the NodeJS:

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 console.log(req.session);
 return res.redirect('http://localhost:4000/index.html'); 
});
```

It works out when authentication was successful. And it actually works, but instead of redirecting to the main page, it returns json to me with an error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

tries to parse this html

Tell me please, where am I doing something wrong?

On the front it is:

```js
let response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/login?email=test@mail.ru&password=123 ', { method: 'POST'});
let result = await response.json();
alert(result.message);
```

Or is it not necessary to do redirect on the server and can it be done on the front in case of successful authorization? from the front works:

```js
window.location.replace("http://localhost:4000 /");
```

Comment: No, it doesn't return JSON, it returns (most likely) HTML which you are trying to parse as JSON on the client side

Comment: What is the request supposed to accomplish and return in the first place?

Comment: the server should redirect to the main page

Comment: But even if you remove this code, the server does not redirect
let result = await response.json();
alert(result.message);

Comment: No, it redirects the AJAX request, it will never redirect the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Your `fetch()` call gets the redirect response, follows that redirect, then because of the redirect, it loads your `http://localhost:4000/index.html` page, the you call `res.json()`, but the body of the request is HTML from `index.html` so you get the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

because that's what happens when you send HTML to `JSON.parse()`.

It's unclear how you intend for this to work.  Right now the server is redirecting to an HTML page, but your client is using `res.json()` which expects a JSON response.  So, either the server isn't sending what the client wants or the client isn't using the right code to read what the server is sending.  Fix one of those.

Keep in mind that when you `res.redirect(...)` on the server and the client is a `fetch()` call in Javascript code, the browser is not redirected.  Instead, the 302 redirect response goes to your Javascript.  By default, `fetch()` will follow the redirect and then the response becomes whatever the redirected URL returns (which in your case is HTML).

If you want the browser itself to get redirected so that it shows a different page, then turn off following of redirects in your `fetch()` call, get the 302 response from `fetch()`, get the `Location` header from that response and set `window.location` to that location.  That will cause the browser to then go to that new URL and load that page into the browser.